# Book ID: Fantasy tale of finding 5 keys for a mysterious door

Tags: story-identification, books

I read a book as a kid about a mysterious/magical door with 5 locks. I believe the door is in the middle of nowhere. Two characters meet at the door, each with one key and knowing each other I believe. One is trying to pick the remaining locks, but getting nowhere. They then go on to search for the remaining keys, together or apart I'm not sure.

"As a kid" means I probably read it somewhere between 1988 and 1994.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The Keys to Paradise](http://www.bookdepository.co.uk/Keys-Paradise-Robert-E-Vardeman/9780450390012) by Robert E. Vardeman.

Giles Grimsmate, a survivor of the Trans wars, has won the golden key in a game of chance. The thief Kajia has the second. The two of them, joined by a part-cat Trans called Petia, quest for the other three keys.